# No 4K option Letv 1s

Tags: camera, hardware, video-recording, front-camera

Last week i bought a Letv 1s mobile. 
In the device specification it states that the mobile has 4K support. And so the hardware info details. But It dont have 4K options in the default camera app.. 
The device is up to date.

[image: camera] [image: about device]
<sup>Camera and DeviceInfo (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Answer (score -3):

Your Android version is not latest, it's old, only Marshmallows Android 6.0 support 4k video resolution.

Comment: This might possibly be true for supporting a 4K screen for playback, but the question is about *recording*.  I worked on the BlackBerry Priv which supports 4K recording on Android 5.1.

Comment: There is no marsmallow update for Letv 1s